# Vlan packet passing through over a layer 2 switch

Tags: networking, packet, switching, vlan

I've got a unmanaged switch in my network and I would like to know if it will pass on vlan encapsulated packets still. Would it understand it?

I have vlan capable hardware on each side of the L2 Switch. A basic map would look like:

Modem > VlanRouter > L2Switch > L3Switch

Does the packet get all the way through?

Comment: That is actually undefined. Some will, some will not, and some will after stripping off the tag. It depends on the switch model and manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks Ron, Tried looking for an answer online but the question was too big to get specific results

Comment: It would make more sense if you swapped the L2 and the L3 switch.

Comment: My l2 is a larger distribution switch and the l3 is only 4 port, I was hoping I don't have to fork out for a 24port l3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've got a unmanaged switch in my network and I would like to know if it will pass on vlan encapsulated packets still.

Many unmanaged switches pass VLAN-tagged frames transparently, but not all do. An unmanaged, yet IEEE 802.1D-compliant switch drops all tagged frames.

> Would it understand it?

No. They're just frames for it.

You should be aware that if a switch just transparently forwards VLAN-tagged frames by MAC address it might cause those frames leaking between VLANs even to a point of working connections - depending on the configuration and implementation of VLANs on the connected managed switches. Generally, trying to use tagged frames across unmanaged switches is a bad idea.